# Keyboard not resign after resigning it in ios 8.3

Tags: ios, ios8.3

i am resigning text field once i get response from server.
but on ios 8.3 its not resigning keyboard.

here is what i am doing .i have resigned text field and after getting response from server but its not getting resign though. and showing me alert and keyboard simultaneously.

Its working on iOS 8.2

**This is my code**

```
-(void)reciveResponseForEmail
{
    [internetDownTimer invalidate];
    [self.emailTextField resignFirstResponder];  //resign text feild
    [ActivityIndicatorUtility finishedWaiting];

    if ([[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"success"] integerValue]==1)
    {
        RegistryConfirmViewController *objRegConfirmVC=[[RegistryConfirmViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RegistryConfirmViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        objRegConfirmVC.signRegistryDetailInfoDict=(NSMutableDictionary*)[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:responseDictionary];

        objRegConfirmVC.isFromEmail=YES;

        objRegConfirmVC.signRegistryAray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.serviceObjectArray];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objRegConfirmVC animated:YES];
    }
    else if (responseDictionary==nil && [responseDictionary count]== 0) //condition apply in case of SERVER failed
    {
        [self showAlertForOfflineMode];
    }
    else
    {
        float iOSVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];

        if (iOSVersion >= 8.0f)
        {

            UIAlertController *alertVC1 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:AMLocalizedString(@"Sorry, we were unable to find any information associated with that email.", nil) preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                           actionWithTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"OK",nil)
                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                           {
                                               [alertVC1 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                               SignRegistryViewController *objSignRegistryVC=[[SignRegistryViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignRegistryViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

                                               objSignRegistryVC.returningGuestEmail=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.emailTextField.text];
                                               objSignRegistryVC.signRegistryArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.serviceObjectArray];

                                               [self.navigationController pushViewController:objSignRegistryVC animated:NO];
                                           }];

            [alertVC1 addAction:cancelAction];

            alertVC1.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
            alertVC1.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentViewController:alertVC1 animated:NO completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alertMe=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:AMLocalizedString(@"Sorry, we were unable to find any information associated with that email.", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertMe show];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keyboard and alert both look simultaneously :(

Comment: How you are resigning keyboard? i couldnt find the code

Comment: i have used [self.emailTextField resignFirstResponder];  before showing alert

Answer (score 0):

Just call this in your view controller when you want to hide the keyboard.

```
[self.view endEditing:NO];
```

Comment: Please add the code where you try yo hide The keyboard and the code of the caller

Comment: [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];

i have used this to present alert view controller in iOS 8.3 and it works for me.